# Shipping method configuration Save Config button doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9

Shipping method configuration Save Config button problem. It does nothing when I click it. I increased input limit value in php.ini. But it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving with the developer console opened. If you are getting any error in the console, open the Magento admin in, incognito window and try it. You will be able to save it. It may be due to some cache.

Comment: No brother. It is not working. I'm not clear about dev. console.